# XDocument: can you skip loading the <!DOCTYPE

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

```
    For Each file In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(inputFolder)
        doc = XDocument.Load(file)
    Next
```

This crashes with a "'[' is an unexpected token. Blah,blah,blah"

It's obviously choking on the first line which is....

```
<!DOCTYPE RCWChapter PUBLIC "-//LSC//DTD RCW Chapter for Authoring//EN" [] >
```

1st, is that INVALID XML?  Why is it hanging on the "[" ?

2nd, Can I somehow load the XML document, but skip the DOCTYPE?  Should I load it as a stream? string.replace it?

Comment: It's choking because there is no system identifier in the doctype declaration. Also, the `[` and the `]` signify the internal subset. They're not needed unless you need to declare something. (Any declaration allowed in the DTD is allowed in the internal subset. You'll usually see entity declarations here.)

Comment: That's why I commented instead of answering; I don't know how to skip it. I've never used XDocument. Do you have control of the input XML? If so, you can add a system identifier.

Comment: No, I don't have control of the input XML.  I just want to skip that first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :  you can remove the internal subset from the DTD by setting the `XDocumentType.InternalSubset` property to null

```
XDocument document = ...;
if (document.DocumentType != null)
document.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null;
```